# Match entire document not just sentence in Regex

Tags: regex

If I want to match 'Foo' and 'Bar' if both are in a document how do I include ANYWHERE not just sentence?

https://regex101.com/r/lW3rJ3/1

Is set to global and shows match on line 1 but not later in the document.

Comment: Could you please precise? Do you mean [`(?s)\bFoo\b.*?Bar`](https://regex101.com/r/lW3rJ3/2)?

Comment: `(?s).*?\bFoo\b.+?\bBar\b.*` but It's a bad idea to do that since it's inefficient. Use your actual pattern, (or test each word separately) test if you obtain a match, and if yes return the source string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm not sure how I'd do otherwise than the (?s). It is literally find 'Foo' if bar exists anywhere later in the doc. In my case it is a description field so not so bad but in any case not sure if there would be any other way to do this.

Comment: @user3649739: Your question is too broad since you didn't say in what context you want to use your regex. (But most of the time, you can test a field with a function in a programming language).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `s` modifier to let `.*` match everything (even across line breaks):

https://regex101.com/r/nH1fH5/1

Comment: That worked, I used (?s) and it worked fine too. Is there any downside to this? I am using it do to replacement of the first word in the case the other words is found anywhere in the doc (description field)